# How to show that $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$ are not homeomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to show that $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$ are not homeomorphic?

My attempt:

On contrary suppose it is then

there exist $f:[0,1)\to (0,1)$ which is continuous

But inverse image of open set is open

So contradiction

Is my argument is correct?

Comment: Your argument is not correct. Are you familiar with connectivity?

Comment: No Sir.Is that connectedness

Comment: I think so (English is not my language). If $0$ is removed from $[0,1)$ then what remains is $(0,1)$ which is connected. But it is not possible to remove a single point from $(0,1)$ such that the remaining space is connected.